# high level java GUI framework

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I've been using netbeans for java gui creations, are there any other better frameworks or ides out there for creating Java GUIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GUI Framework is not an IDE and conversely!

NetBeans is an IDE, but also provided the NetBeans RCP framework (but you don't need to use NetBeans IDE to use NetBeans RCP).

If you main problem is designing UI (panels, forms...) then you have two options:

- create the UI by hand, for that
  you'll need to use a LayoutManager
  that has an easy API (good examples:
  DesignGridLayout and MigLayout)
- create the UI with a UI designer (in
  an IDE), I will never advise this
  option because the generated code is
  obscure and unmaintainable; also,
  this enforces the same UI for all
  developers in the team.

Now if you are looking for framework to build a UI application (not talking just about forms), then you have a few of them, but in most cases, they are either too "big" (eg, NetBeans RCP or Spring RCP), or provide only one part of the features required for a UI framework.

You may want to start with Swing Application Framework (or its offspring BSAF) although they both seem dead by now, they still can be used in a real-life application, if you're not afraid to fix some bugs yourself (it's not really difficult actually, because the codebase is quite small).

Answer (score 1):

try [javaFX](http://javafx.com/) for rich UI

Comment: the OP tagged his question with "Swing", hence JavaFX is not a valid answer (although it could be a valid comment).

Comment: @jfpoilpret I beg to differ, question is about creating Java GUI, not about correctness of Tags

Comment: @mKorbel I see your point, but if the OP tagged his question with " Swing" I guess he has no interest in somethign else like JFX or SWT for instance. At least, if I was the OP I wouldn't like an answer telling me that "you should choose another technology" ;-)

Comment: @jfpoilpret: i advice you , dot be rigid on tags that he/she used, question asked in way that `any other better frameworks or ideas`, so be general

Comment: look like as real storm in a small glass cup :-) here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try different [look and feels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612888/what-does-look-and-feel-java-swing-mean) available for swing to give your app a rich look.

Or if you still want to go for another then try one of the following as an alternative to swing: [JavaFx](http://javafx.com/) or [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) or [Buoy](http://buoy.sourceforge.net/)